# VBA Not Seeing HTML Element

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

Currently, I have a successful excel-based web-scraper program that goes through my company's project tracking system and grabs information I need (Project Manager, Release Date, etc.) My problem is that I am trying to add a new functionality that checks a secondary tab on each open ticket panel which results in the program not seeing the href/button (only after first ticket) and crashing.

Also:

- For the first ticket, the program runs smoothly and clicks on the tab, it messes up when on the second tab
- The id is correct as I checked after the crash, and I even added a 5 second application.wait but still no luck.
- After the crash, when I hover over my object that was intended to be the "button", it says impactObj = Nothing

[The secondary tab I am accessing on each ticket: "Impact Analysis"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CniGE.png)

Clicking Impact Analysis Tab (counter is my iterator since Ids change between tickets):

```
    identification3 = "dijit_layout_TabContainer_1_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_" & CStr(5 + (counter * 18))
    Set impactObj = doc.getElementById(identification3)
    impactObj.Click
```

Error appears on this line:

> impactObj.Click

Note: Website is internal intranet only

Thanks

EDIT: Are there any common problems or errors that occur when switching between pages that could be responsible for this?

EDIT: Adding code:

```
Sub CQscrub()

Dim i As Long
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim objCollection2 As Object
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim numbers() As String
Dim size As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim objLead As Object
Dim lead As String
Dim state As String
Dim releasedate As String
Dim inv As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim identification As String
Dim identification2 As String
Dim identification3 As String
Dim identification4 As String
Dim closeObj As Object
Dim existingTab As Boolean
Dim searchStringObj As Object

' Creating dynamic array
size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1)) - 4
ReDim numbers(size)
For row = 0 To size
    numbers(row) = Cells(row + 10, 1).Value
Next row ' Check : Cells(row, 2) = numbers(row - 10)

' Creating IE instance
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Height = 1000
ie.Width = 1000
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://clearquest/cqweb/"
Application.StatusBar = "Loading http://clearquest/cqweb"
Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Application.StatusBar = "Please wait..."

' Second declaration zone
Dim doc As HTMLDocument, yourObj As Object, stateObj As Object, dateObj As Object, invObj As Object, impactObj As Object, tabObj As Object
Set doc = ie.document
' First searching for "search" bar and inputting WR
Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "cqFindRecordString" Then
        Set searchStringObj = objCollection(i)
        'objCollection(i).Value = numbers(counter)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
Set objElement = ie.document.getElementById("cqFindRecordButton")

' Starting main loop
For counter = 0 To size - 1
    ' Clicking search button
    searchStringObj.Value = numbers(counter)
    objElement.Click
    Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    ' Section scraping the webpage
    ' Finding the IT Lead
    identification = "cq_widget_CqFilteringSelect_" & CStr(9 + (counter * 46))
    Range("D" & (10 + counter)).Value = identification ' Test prompt
    Set yourObj = doc.getElementById(identification)
    lead = yourObj.Value
    Range("B" & (10 + counter)).Value = lead
    ' Finding WR State
    identification2 = "cq_widget_CqTextBox_" & CStr(2 + (counter * 3))
    Range("E" & (10 + counter)).Value = identification2 ' Test prompt
    Set stateObj = doc.getElementById(identification2)
    state = stateObj.Value
    Range("C" & (10 + counter)).Value = state
    ' Clicking Impact Analysis Tab
    ' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''' Problem Area '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    identification3 = "dijit_layout_TabContainer_1_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_" & CStr(5 + (counter * 18))
     Range("F" & (10 + counter)).Value = identification3 ' Test prompt
     Set impactObj = doc.getElementById(identification3)
     impactObj.Click
     Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
         DoEvents
     Loop
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
     ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Finding UAT Involvement
    ' Set yourObj = doc.getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
    ' cqTable dojoDndContainer
    'identification = "cq_widget_CqTable_" & CStr(7 + (counter * 9))
    'Set invObj = doc.getElementsByClassName("cqListBox cqReadonlyControl cqListControl cqListBoxReadOnly dijitReadOnly")(7)
    'inv = invObj.innerText
    'Range("E" & (10 + counter)).Value = inv
    ' Closing tab
    Set closeObj = doc.getElementsByClassName("dijitInline dijitTabCloseButton dijitTabCloseIcon")(0)
    closeObj.Click
    Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
Next counter
' Closing final open tab
Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
Set closeObj = doc.getElementsByClassName("dijitInline dijitTabCloseButton dijitTabCloseIcon")(0)
closeObj.Click
Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
' Click logout, enter password in login, click login?
' Closing down program
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""
MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to show more of your code.  It's difficult to make suggestions without any access to (or screenshot of) the relevant HTML source.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, I added the complete program, the real action happens within my "for counter = 0..." loop. Thanks again

Comment: If any action causes a navigation then you need to reset your `doc` reference, otherwise it still points to a previous document, not to the currently-loaded one.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the insight

Comment: Are trying to read ClearQuest data? If yes, then you can chose a better approach, like programmatically downloading the data as XML and importing the XML file in Excel.

Comment: @M.R. That sounds really interesting! Could you expand on that idea or provide an example?